# Creating an SQLAlchemy column to dynamically generate a list of models with an expression

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to create a relationship column on my model, where it will be built with an expression so that it can be queried.

Here's a brief example of my setup:

I have each application (eg. `Python`) stored in the `App` table. Each version of the application (eg. `Python 3.7`) is stored under the `AppVersion` table.

My items (in the `Item` table) have a minimum and maximum supported version per application. This is done with the `ItemVersion` table, with `ItemVersion.version_min` and `ItemVersion.version_max`, for example:

- `min_version=None, max_version=None`: Compatible with all versions
- `min_version=None, max_version=27`: Compatible with Python 2 and below
- `min_version=37, max_version=None`: Compatible with Python 3 and above
- `min_version=37, max_version=39`: Compatible with Python 3.7 to 3.9

In this case, I want to generate an expression to return a list of `AppVersion` records compatible with my item.

Below I have used `@hybrid_property` as an example to mock up how `ItemVersion.versions` and `Item.versions` *should* work. I need it to be compatible with queries though, which this is not (eg. `Item.versions.any(AppVersion.id == 1)`).

```
from sqlalchemy import select, create_engine, Column, Integer, ForeignKey, String, case, and_, or_
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker, column_property
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy


Engine = create_engine('sqlite://')

Base = declarative_base(Engine)

session = sessionmaker(Engine)()


class App(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'app'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(64))
    versions = relationship('AppVersion', back_populates='app')

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name


class AppVersion(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'app_version'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    app_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('app.id'), nullable=False)
    value = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

    app = relationship('App', foreign_keys=app_id, back_populates='versions', innerjoin=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.app.name}:{self.value}'


class ItemVersion(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'item_version'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    item_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('item.id'))
    app_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('app.id'))
    version_min_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('app_version.id'), nullable=True)
    version_max_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('app_version.id'), nullable=True)

    item = relationship('Item', foreign_keys=item_id)
    app = relationship('App', foreign_keys=app_id)
    version_min = relationship('AppVersion', foreign_keys=version_min_id)
    version_max = relationship('AppVersion', foreign_keys=version_max_id)

    @hybrid_property
    def versions(self):
        # All versions
        if self.version_min is None and self.version_max is None:
            return self.app.versions
        # Single version
        elif self.version_min == self.version_max:
            return [self.version_min]
        # Max version and below
        elif self.version_min is None:
            return [version for version in self.app.versions
                            if version.value <= self.version_max.value]
        # Min version and above
        elif self.version_max is None:
            return [version for version in self.app.versions
                            if self.version_min.value <= version.value]
        # Custom range
        return [version for version in self.app.versions
                 if self.version_min.value <= version.value <= self.version_max.value]


class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'item'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    item_versions = relationship('ItemVersion', back_populates='item')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Item {self.id}'

    @hybrid_property
    def versions(self):
        versions = []
        for item_version in self.item_versions:
            versions.extend(item_version.versions)
        return versions


Base.metadata.create_all()


py = App(name='Python')
session.add(py)
py27 = AppVersion(app=py, value=27)
py37 = AppVersion(app=py, value=37)
py38 = AppVersion(app=py, value=38)
py39 = AppVersion(app=py, value=39)

session.add(Item(item_versions=[ItemVersion(app=py)])) # [Python:27, Python:37, Python:38, Python:39]
session.add(Item(item_versions=[ItemVersion(app=py, version_min=py37)])) # [Python:37, Python:38, Python:39]
session.add(Item(item_versions=[ItemVersion(app=py, version_max=py37)])) # [Python:27, Python:37]
session.add(Item(item_versions=[ItemVersion(app=py, version_min=py27, version_max=py27)])) # [Python:27]

session.commit()

for item in session.execute(select(Item)).scalars():
    print(f'{item}: {item.versions}')
```

My attempts so far have hit issues *before* I've got to writing the actual query.

With relationships they don't apply any filter on `value`:

```
class ItemVersion(Base):
    ...
    versions = relationship(
        AppVersion,
        primaryjoin=and_(AppVersion.app_id == App.id, AppVersion.value == 0),
        secondaryjoin=app_id == App.id,
        secondary=App.__table__,
        viewonly=True, uselist=True,
    )

# sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not locate any relevant foreign key columns for primary join condition 'app_version.app_id = item_version.app_id' on relationship ItemVersion.versions.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or are annotated in the join condition with the foreign() annotation.
```

With `column_property` (which I could link with a relationship) it doesn't like more than 1 result:

```
class ItemVersion(Base):
    ...
    version_ids = column_property(
        select(AppVersion.id).where(AppVersion.app_id == app_id)
    )

# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) sub-select returns 3 columns - expected 1
```

**This would be my ideal result:**

```
class ItemVersion(Base):
    versions = # generate expression

class Item(Base):
    ...
    item_versions = relationship('ItemVersion', back_populates='item')
    versions = association_proxy('item_versions', 'versions')
```

If anyone has a particular section of documentation to point to that would also be appreciated, I'm just struggling a lot with this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible via a relationship but it took a *lot* of trial and error with joins to get there. Below is what was needed to get it working, although I wouldn't be surprised if there's a more optimal way.

```
class ItemVersion(Base):
    ...
    version_min_val = column_property(
        select(AppVersion.value)
        .where(AppVersion.id == version_min_id)
        .correlate_except(AppVersion)
        .scalar_subquery(),
    )
    version_max_val = column_property(
        select(AppVersion.value)
        .where(AppVersion.id == version_max_id)
        .correlate_except(AppVersion)
        .scalar_subquery(),
    )
    versions = relationship(
        AppVersion,
        primaryjoin=and_(
            app_id == AppVersion.app_id,
            case(
                [and_(version_min_id == None, version_max_id == None), literal(True)],
                [and_(version_min_id == None, version_max_id != None), AppVersion.value <= version_max_val],
                [and_(version_min_id != None, version_max_id == None), version_min_val <= AppVersion.value],
                else_=and_(version_min_val <= AppVersion.value, AppVersion.value <= version_max_val),
            )
        ),
        viewonly=True, uselist=True,
    )

class Item(Base):
    ...
    versions = relationship(
        AppVersion,
        primaryjoin=and_(
            id == ItemVersion.item_id,
            case(
                [and_(ItemVersion.version_min_id == None, ItemVersion.version_max_id == None), literal(True)],
                [and_(ItemVersion.version_min_id == None, ItemVersion.version_max_id != None), AppVersion.value <= ItemVersion.version_max_val],
                [and_(ItemVersion.version_min_id != None, ItemVersion.version_max_id == None), ItemVersion.version_min_val <= AppVersion.value],
                else_=and_(ItemVersion.version_min_val <= AppVersion.value, AppVersion.value <= ItemVersion.version_max_val),
            )
        ),
        secondaryjoin=ItemVersion.app_id == AppVersion.app_id,
        secondary=ItemVersion.__table__,
        viewonly=True, uselist=True,
    )
```

Full code I used for testing:

```
from sqlalchemy import select, create_engine, Column, Integer, ForeignKey, String, case, and_, literal
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker, column_property
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Engine = create_engine('sqlite://')

Base = declarative_base(Engine)

session = sessionmaker(Engine)()

class App(Base):
    """Each App has name and list of versions."""
    __tablename__ = 'app'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(64))
    versions = relationship('AppVersion', back_populates='app')

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

class AppVersion(Base):
    """Each App version has a particular value."""
    __tablename__ = 'app_version'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    app_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('app.id'), nullable=False)
    value = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

    app = relationship('App', foreign_keys=app_id, back_populates='versions', innerjoin=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.app.name}:{self.value}'

class ItemVersion(Base):
    """The item version links a particular item to an App and it's min/max versions.
    Using the min and max versions, a range of compatible versions can be generated.
    """
    __tablename__ = 'item_version'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    item_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('item.id'))
    app_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('app.id'))
    version_min_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('app_version.id'), nullable=True)
    version_max_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('app_version.id'), nullable=True)

    item = relationship('Item', foreign_keys=item_id)
    app = relationship('App', foreign_keys=app_id)
    version_min = relationship('AppVersion', foreign_keys=version_min_id)
    version_max = relationship('AppVersion', foreign_keys=version_max_id)

    version_min_val = column_property(
        select(AppVersion.value)
        .where(AppVersion.id == version_min_id)
        .correlate_except(AppVersion)
        .scalar_subquery(),
    )
    version_max_val = column_property(
        select(AppVersion.value)
        .where(AppVersion.id == version_max_id)
        .correlate_except(AppVersion)
        .scalar_subquery(),
    )

    versions = relationship(
        AppVersion,
        primaryjoin=and_(
            app_id == AppVersion.app_id,
            case(
                [and_(version_min_id == None, version_max_id == None), literal(True)],
                [and_(version_min_id == None, version_max_id != None), AppVersion.value <= version_max_val],
                [and_(version_min_id != None, version_max_id == None), version_min_val <= AppVersion.value],
                else_=and_(version_min_val <= AppVersion.value, AppVersion.value <= version_max_val),
            )
        ),
        viewonly=True, uselist=True,
    )

class Item(Base):
    """Each item may have multiple compatible applications with specific versions."""
    __tablename__ = 'item'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    item_versions = relationship('ItemVersion', back_populates='item')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Item {self.id}'

    versions = relationship(
        AppVersion,
        primaryjoin=and_(
            id == ItemVersion.item_id,
            case(
                [and_(ItemVersion.version_min_id == None, ItemVersion.version_max_id == None), literal(True)],
                [and_(ItemVersion.version_min_id == None, ItemVersion.version_max_id != None), AppVersion.value <= ItemVersion.version_max_val],
                [and_(ItemVersion.version_min_id != None, ItemVersion.version_max_id == None), ItemVersion.version_min_val <= AppVersion.value],
                else_=and_(ItemVersion.version_min_val <= AppVersion.value, AppVersion.value <= ItemVersion.version_max_val),
            )
        ),
        secondaryjoin=ItemVersion.app_id == AppVersion.app_id,
        secondary=ItemVersion.__table__,
        viewonly=True, uselist=True,
    )

Base.metadata.create_all()

py = App(name='Python')
py27 = AppVersion(app=py, value=27)
py37 = AppVersion(app=py, value=37)
py38 = AppVersion(app=py, value=38)
py39 = AppVersion(app=py, value=39)
maya = App(name='Maya')
m22 = AppVersion(app=maya, value=2022)
m23 = AppVersion(app=maya, value=2023)

# [Python:27, Python:37, Python:38, Python:39, Maya:2022, Maya:2023]
session.add(Item(item_versions=[ItemVersion(app=py), ItemVersion(app=maya)]))
# [Python:37, Python:38, Python:39]
session.add(Item(item_versions=[ItemVersion(app=py, version_min=py37)]))
# [Python:27, Python:37]
session.add(Item(item_versions=[ItemVersion(app=py, version_max=py37)]))
# [Python:27]
session.add(Item(item_versions=[ItemVersion(app=py, version_min=py27, version_max=py27)]))
# [Python:27, Python:37, Python:38]
session.add(Item(item_versions=[ItemVersion(app=py, version_min=py27, version_max=py38)]))
# [Python:27, Python:39, Maya:2022]
session.add(Item(item_versions=[ItemVersion(app=py, version_max=py27), ItemVersion(app=py, version_min=py39), ItemVersion(app=maya, version_min=m22, version_max=m22)]))

session.commit()

stmt = select(Item).where(Item.versions.any(AppVersion.app.has(App.name == 'Maya')))
for item in session.execute(stmt).scalars():
    print(f'{item}: {item.versions}')
```